# swift 3 Second TableView segue not showing in Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationcontroller

EDIT 2: Added a half-solution at bottom.  Still open to a full solution

EDIT 1: Added images.

I need help fixing navigation between a second and third tableview.

I have a Navigation Controller, and three table views.  The first two show up fine such that clicking a dynamic tableview cell > in the first tableview moves to the second tableview.  However the second tableview cell chevron > while set in the storyboard (Accessory: Disclosure Indicator) doesn't show up during runtime, and therefore clicking on it does not move to the third tableview.  I need help fixing that.

In each case I Ctrl+linked the cells to the next tableview in storyboard as show, and have prepare for segue in the previous tableview controllers. However only one works and the other seems orphaned.

If you could suggest a checklist in making sure the Navigation Controller works across three tableviews that would be helpful.  Not sure what code to show so I'll post both segues.  But it might not be a segue issue so I don't know.

first tableview Weeks works going to second tableview Leagues.  Loads json file depending on what is clicked.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toLeagues"
    {
            let leaguesController = segue.destination as! LeaguesViewController
            // pass the selected row
            let selectedRow = self.tableView.indexPath(for: sender as! UITableViewCell)!.row
            if selectedRow == 0
            {
                leaguesController.weekFileName = "sports_week_1"
            }
            else
            {
                leaguesController.weekFileName = "sports_week_2"
            }
    }
```

But second tableview Leagues doesn't work going to third tableview Games

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toGames"
    {

        let gamesController = segue.destination as! GamesViewController
        // pass the selected row
        let selectedRow = self.tableView.indexPath(for: sender as! UITableViewCell)!.row

        gamesController.gameName = selectedRow.description
    }
}
```

EDIT 1: Added images:

**Starts off fine in first tableview...**
[image: starts off fine, get > to move to next view]

**Stops here in second tableview, can't move to third tableview**
[image]

EDIT 2: Half solution

I found a half solution.  Menu item now opens new view, only that the chevron appears after the fact.  didSelectRowAt adds the missing disclosure indicator directly and goes to the new view controller.  Couldn't find a viewWillAppear with IndexPath so I opted for didSelectRowAt.  Works when clicked at least.  Just the disclosure indicator missing on initial load. How to load the accessoryType before the view runs?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        cell?.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator

        // force menu to move to GamesViewController
        let myGamesView = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "gamesView")
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(myGamesView, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: Can you add `cellForRow` for `LeaguesViewController` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `accessoryType` in `cellForRowAt` instead of `didSelectRowAt`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourIdentifier") as! YourCustomCell

    //Your other code
    cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
    return cell 
}
```

Comment: I see, so I can just add cell.accessoryType to the cell.  That makes sense.  That fixes the chevron.  Thank you.  Still need to force the other view to open but this works.  

Now I notice that my second segue will never return the text of the cell to the third view.  gamesController.gameName = selectedRow.description is wrong.   I'll have to use the indexPath to get the cell to then get the text.

Comment: @sf2k Don't get your comment can you please be more specific about your issue. Also if you are working with Segue the there is no need to push the ViewController it will automatically pushed using the segue

Comment: Answer accepted.  My issue now is that I am not using the segue properly.  gamesController.gameName  = somethingsomething

Comment: @sf2k Can you show the Segue image from storyboard for this second segue, Select this second segue and take screenshot the will give us idea from where you have created segue ? Is from cell or detaildesclosure ?

Comment: can't send an image at the moment.  Segue on the storyboard is indicated from the prototype cell to the next view controller.  Actually I found an error, I hadn't set a segue identifier in the storyboard segue.  Now I just need to clean up the variable being passed from one view to another.

Comment: @sf2k Thats great that you find the issue, if you still phase any problem inform here will look after it.